# Can the signature of quadratic form be negative?

Tags: quadratic-forms, ordered-fields

I have a canonical form of the quadratic form. The canonical form is $y_1^2-y_2^2-y_3^2$.

So, the rank will be 3, and the the index will be 1. So, by the formula for signature,

signature = 2s-r = 2(1) - 3 = -1

I wanted to know if this is possible, can the signature of a quadratic form be negative?

Comment: not sure about your formula, but signature is an ordered triple?

Comment: @cineel if you know the rank of the form, then the signature can be equivalently expressed as the number of positive and negative eigenvalues $(p,n)$ or as the signed sum of those eigenvalues $p-n=2p-r$. So yes, the signature can be negative.

Comment: Is there a reason why you ask if this is possible? You have a formula, and obviously this formula sometimes gives negative numbers, as in your example, so the signature can be negative.

Comment: @EthanDlugie thanks.
I know that a formula can give a negative answer, but I was not sure whether the signature can be negative. I thought there might be a mistake in the question itself because I solved everything without any mistakes.